# java.util.NoSuchElementException: Column not found ID in table demo.usertable in Cassandra Spark

Tags: scala, cassandra, apache-spark

I am try to write RDD[CassandraRow] into existing Cassandra Table using Spark-cassandra-Connector. Here is my piece of code

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(getClass.getSimpleName)
            .setMaster("local[*]")
            .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", host)
        val sc = new SparkContext("local[*]", keySpace, conf)
val rdd = sc.textFile("hdfs://hdfs-host:8020/Users.csv")
val columns = Array("ID", "FirstName", "LastName", "Email", "Country")
val types = Array("int", "string", "string", "string", "string")
val crdd=rdd.map(p => {
            var tokens = p.split(",")
            new CassandraRow(columns,tokens)
        })
val targetedColumns = SomeColumns.seqToSomeColumns(columns)
crdd.saveToCassandra(keySpace, tableName, targetedColumns,  WriteConf.fromSparkConf(conf))
```

When I run this code I get following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: Column not found ID in table demo.usertable
```

here is actual schema of table

```
CREATE TABLE usertable (
  id int,
  country text,
  email text,
  firstname text,
  lastname text,
  PRIMARY KEY ((id))
)
```

Any suggestion?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keyspace, table and column names are case sensitive in Cassandra.  Have you tried adjusting your code to use the same case as the table definition? (For example use 'id' instead of 'ID').

Comment: Also a possibility, the error message your shared references "demo.usertabl", is it possible you specified that as your table, or was it a copy-paste mistake?

Comment: @AndyTolbert sir , i have this problem ...My cassandra table columns in lower case like below
CREATE TABLE model_family_by_id(
model_family_id int PRIMARY KEY,
model_family text,
create_date   date,
last_update_date date,
model_family_name text
);

Comment: my dataframe schema is like this
 root
           |-- MODEL_FAMILY_ID: decimal(38,10) (nullable = true)
           |-- MODEL_FAMILY: string (nullable = true)
           |-- CREATE_DATE: timestamp (nullable = true)
           |-- LAST_UPDATE_DATE: timestamp (nullable = true)
           |-- MODEL_FAMILY_NAME: string (nullable = true)

Comment: @AndyTolbert So while insert into tabException in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: Columns not found in table sample_cbd.model_family_by_id: MODEL_FAMILY_ID, MODEL_FAMILY, CREATE_DATE, LAST_UPDATE_DATE, MODEL_FAMILY_NAME
 at com.datastax.spark.connector.SomeColumns.selectFrom(ColumnSelector.scala:44)
le i am getting error how to fix this ???

Comment: Can we invoke saveToCassandra on dataframe? when i do in my code it is saying unknown method ....ofcouse i added  import com.datastax.spark.connector._ so what else i need to do ?